# Implementing tooltip on the right bar button of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, tooltip, ios11

I need to implement a tooltip on the right bar button item of navigation controller which says like *'see travellers around you'* which should always be visible on UI pointing at that right bar button.

The pod which I am using in my project for tooltip is [CMPopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView). Rest everywhere its working fine, but its not working correctly in case of this right bar button item. Please suggest something correct here.

Comment: which right bar button item ? and Rest everywhere means where ?

Comment: add some tried code or image to show where it is working and not.

Comment: i didn't get your problem. Is the tool tip visible on `UIBarButtonItem` click event?

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in `viewDidAppear`,

```
CMPopTipView *navBarLeftButtonPopTipView = [[CMPopTipView alloc] initWithMessage:@"A Message"];
navBarLeftButtonPopTipView.delegate = self;
[navBarLeftButtonPopTipView presentPointingAtBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem animated:YES];
```

Reference : [CMPopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView)